# Storing A Users Profile Privacy Settings

Tags: mysql, database-design

Suppose I have a database with the following Users table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users (
`id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`last_name` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
`date_of_birth` date DEFAULT NULL,
`home_phone` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`mobile_phone` varchar(25) DEFAULT NULL,
`address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`image` longblob,
`added` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`modified` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`user`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='User Profile';
```

What would be the best way to store whether some of this information is public or private.

Currently what I do involves having a separate table that stores whether this field is public (public=1) or not (public=0 or not in table)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `user_perms` (
`user` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`field` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
`public` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`user`,`field`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

(Relations not shown, but `user_perms.user` references `users.id`)

So to make a user's first name public, I would do the following:

```
INSERT INTO `user_perms` (`user`, `field`, `public`) 
VALUES ('123', 'first_name', 1);
```

My question is: **Is there a better way to represent this profile in the database**?

I've thought of maybe storing each profile field, referencing its owners user ID and it's privacy setting in their own table:

```
| UserID |   Field    | Field_Value | Public |
   123     first_name      Marco      1
```

It seems to be a good solution because it doesn't require me to update the `users` table everytime I need to add a new profile field. Would this scale well? At 1m users, assuming each user fills out 5 fields, there would be 5m table rows.